# GM power steering fluid -- what kind do I need?

Tags: pontiac, power-steering, gm, g6, fluid

I have a 2007 Pontiac G6 (3.5L V6) that needs power steering fluid.
However, I **do not know what type is compatible** with my vehicle.

My manual simply says:

> GM Power Steering Fluid (GM Part No. U.S. 98021184, in Canada 89021186)

[image]

**So what type of PS fluid is compatible??**

- I called Autozone and they said there was no information on file for a 2007 Pontiac G6 and recommended that I look online.
- However, I've searched numerous sites/forums (e.g., [here](http://www.gm-trucks.com/forums/topic/156912-gm-power-steering-fluid-specs-anybody-have-them/), [here](https://www.corvetteforum.com/forums/c6-corvette-general-discussion/3140378-power-steering-fluid-2-gm-part-numbers.html), [here](https://www.bobistheoilguy.com/forums/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=3162748), [here](http://www.gm-trucks.com/forums/topic/153277-gm-power-steering-fluid/), etc.) and still do not have a *definitive*/*consistent* answer.
- Additionally, neither [this](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/4552/why-did-gm-supercede-change-part-numbers-for-their-power-steering-fluid) SE question nor [this](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/12637/power-steering-fluid-compatibility) question seemed to provide specific enough info to help me either.

**My Questions:**

1. **What "*type*" of PS fluid does my 2007 G6 use? (i.e., I need more than a part #)?**

   - For exmaple, my car takes *DEXRON VI* transmission fluid -- is there a similar general type/name of PS fluid I can look for across brands?
2. **I can't find GM part# 89021184 for purchase and can only find 89021185 -- Are these compatible? What's the difference?**

   - The sites I link to above suggest conflicting reasons: some say the part numbers differ in size (i.e., fluid oz's) only, while others claim that that is wrong and that the part number has simply changed. Are either correct?
3. **Also, what non-GM brand PS fluid works in my 2007 G6?**

   Again, the sites I link to provide inconsistent info, so I'm looking for something more definitive (and preferably supported with reputable source info).

Thanks!

Comment: If you google "gm 89021184" - one of the part numbers from your manual picture - you'll see a number of sources for AC Delco (aka, GM brand) PS fluid.

Comment: I just changed out the the power steering fluid in my 13' Cadillac Escalade that also calls for "GM or equivalent" power steering fluid. I wondered the same thing but after some research got what was on sale as it seems the ACDelco fluid is pretty much standard P.S. fluid same as Prestone and the like. I just flushed it with Lucas Oil P.S. fluid and it seems to be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short Answer

**89021185 is compatible with 89021184 (and both are now superseded by part# 19329450).**

---

#### Long Answer

I talked to GM parts department and they told me the 98021184 part number has been changed to **part# 19329450**.

The associate had nothing to say regarding 89021185, and simply pointed me toward using 19329450.

- However, I can only find this fluid for 200% the price of the [best deal](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BK7MFBY) on 89021185 -_- .

**Update:**

Spoke to a dealer rep and he looked into 89021185 specifically for me. He said he had no info about this part number. However, he said his system shows that **89021185 is *also* superseded by part# 19329450.**

- Therefore, **89021185 is compatible with 89021184** (and **both are now superseded by part# 19329450**).

Comment: I readily find 19329450 for ~$4/pint..

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't anything fancy you will need for an 07 G6. Some European cars will use CHFS11 and Honda will have it's own blend, but other than that you can use a universal power steering fluid, and by that I mean literally a bottle of "power steering fluid". I would recommend you use a quality brand such as Lucas and not the Autozone off brand, but they probably come from the same place anyways. As far as getting a specific part number for a GM vehicle. being in the auto industry for quite some time, I would recommend you contact your local GM dealer for the specific fluid.

As a precaution make sure the bottle does not indicate it's for Asian, European, or any special application. If in doubt ask your local parts man, or GM, if a fluid type is intended for vehicles not made in America.